# Алгоритм проверки корректности введенного пароля

Tags: javascript, html

Вывести окно ввода пароля. 
Тип пароля: текстовый; 
Алгоритм проверки корректности пароля: в пароле 3 буквы б.

Нужно сделать функцию проверки введенных символов javascript, но я не понимаю, как составить алгоритм проверки.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

```js
function Input() {
  login_ok = false;
  password = "";
  password = prompt("Пароль", "");
  password = password.toLowerCase();
  if ( ? ? ? ? ) /*вот здесь не понимаю, как составить условие*/ {
    login_ok = true;
    window.location = "order.html";
  }
  if (login_ok == false) {
    window.location = "sait.html";
  }
}
```

Comment: function Input(){
login_ok = false;
password = "";
password = prompt("Пароль","");
password = password.toLowerCase();

if ( ???? )   /*вот здесь не понимаю, как составить условие

{
login_ok=true;
window.location="order.html";
}
if (login_ok==false) 
{ 
 window.location="sait.html";}
}

Comment: Это учебное задание?

Comment: Я конечно очень поражаюсь от полёта воображения ответивших тут. Человек только учится и ему нужно самое простое решение!

Comment: Elly, мы все ждём отклика от вас.

Comment: **Почитайте справку:** [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

```
/^([^б]*[б]){3}[^б]*$/.test(password)
```

Comment: для чего в этой регулярке `[^б]*` ?

Comment: @MedvedevDev, чтобы лишние `б` не попадали под `.`.

Comment: а, сообразил, норм xDD

Answer (score 1):

```
password = password.toLowerCase();
var bCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
  if (password[i] == "б")
    bCount++;
}
if (bCount == 3) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Парадокс, вроде ответили и Qwertiy и Igor, но оба их варианта как будто не самые логичные и читаемые О_о Накину свой, чисто для "обсудить":

```
const match = password.match(/б/g);

if(match && match.length === 3) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Если ни одной `б` нет, то упадёт

Comment: @Qwertiy, резонно.

Comment: Да, так лучше :)

Answer (score 1):

Ладно, если уж хочется простой вариант, то:

```
password.split("б").length === 4
```

Comment: В каком случае здесь нужно проверять на тип? По-моему достаточно ==, а не ===

Comment: @Bharata, есть рекомендация всегда использовать `===` если это возможно.

Comment: Хотел бы я увидеть кто такое советует. Если в файле таких сравнений 1000 и это отдавать 1.000.000 пользователям, то это лишние расходы и на сервере и на клиенте.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое и самое короткое решение:

```js
function Input()
{
  login_ok = false;
  password = "";
  password = prompt("Пароль", "");
  // согласно условию задачи даже эта строка лишняя:
  //password = password.toLowerCase();
  if(password == "ббб")
  {
    login_ok = true;
    alert("login_ok = true");
    //здесь, на stackoverflow следующая строка вызовет ошибку, т.к. такого файла тут нет
    window.location = "order.html";
  }
  if(login_ok == false)
  {
    alert("login_ok = false");
    //здесь, на stackoverflow следующая строка вызовет ошибку, т.к. такого файла тут нет
    window.location = "sait.html";
  }
}

Input()
```

Comment: Эм.. Вообще-то в условии не сказано, ни что они должны быть подряд, ни что кроме них в пароле ничего быть не должно. Все решения кроме твоего проверяют на "ровно 3 буквы `б` среди любых других символов".

Comment: @Qwertiy, я думаю, что новичок имел это ввиду между строк, и что ему просто непонятно как проверить пароль. Возможно, что я, конечно, и ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Bharata, лучше дать ответ строго по форме вопроса, а потом поправить в ходе обсуждения по средствам комментариев (попутно можно и вопрос подкорректировать), чем давать ответ включающий в себя домыслы (даже если вы угадали).